# How to get return value from cordova plugin function to variable?

Tags: javascript, function, cordova, variables, cordova-plugins

I have plugin androidIDFA and I need to get result from this plugin and put it to variable.
Code:

```
function successADID(result) {
  console.log("androidIDFA: " + result.adId);
}
function errorADID(result) {
  console.log("androidIDFA err: " + result);
}
androidIDFA.getAdId(successADID, errorADID);
```

Comment: put it in a variable in those callback functions where you have `result` available - but, a) avoid adding variables to the global scope, and b) you'll have no way of knowing, outside of those callbacks, when the variable is set - since it appears that `androidIDFA.getAdId` is probably calling those callbacks asynchronously ... without more context to how you want to use that result, it's hard to say what the best course of action is

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for reply. I have few such plugins and I need to get results from all of them and than send all data to my server in one request.

Comment: without seeing any example of your workflow, it's hard to help - in an `async` function you could do `const [{value: result, reason:error}] = await Promise.allSettled([new Promise(androidIDFA.getAdId)]);` for example - you'd end up with `result` and `error` (only one of which would have a value of course) - you could do multiple such calls (they'd run one after the other) with different variable names for `result` and `error`